# CodeIgniter - Controller - loading view with template

Tags: php, codeigniter

I have a template design for each page and it is working without any issues, now i have a problem with form validation and template.

```
my_controller   //inside my controller

function __construct()
{
    parent::__construct();
    $this->load->library('template');     
}


public function page1(){
   $this->template->write('title', 'COMPANY');
   $this->template->write_view('content', 'company');
   $this->template->render();
}

public function validation(){
     //for page1 form validation
     //form validation here

     if ($this->form_validation->run() == FALSE){
         // here i need to call my page1 again to update the form error
         // option1: $this->load->view('page1');  // this is just loading page1, not loading with my template, template file has header, footer, js and css file includes
         // option2: $this->template->load('template', 'page1'); // it is loading page withing page
         // option3: $this->template->write_view('content', 'page1');
         //          $this->template->render();  // this is same as option2
     } else {
     $this->load->view('formsuccess');
 }
}
```

So my question is how do i can call same view (within one controller) for multiple time when it is already loaded with template?

### EDITED for more clarity

My template file is just single file ( not separated like header, footer) will have all header information and footer information with common style sheet and script files.
I am having

```
<?php $content ?>
```

variable name inside the template to pass my content from controller.

for example see my page1 function(),

```
   $this->template->write('title', 'COMPANY'); // to write a value on variable
   $this->template->write_view('content', 'page1'); //view page to write on template
   $this->template->render(); // final template render
```

This page is having form validation, if my form validation is FALSE, how do i can reload the template page with validation error?

I have tried so many way, please check my option1, 2, 3, i never got a solution to solve this, now please tell me how do i can solve this?

Comment: Your Controller structure is very unconventional.  It might be best if you first look at and follow the tutorials and demos within the CodeIgniter documentation.

Comment: In other words, you would have a Controller function called `edit` and it's accessed at `yourdomain.com/my_controller/edit`.  This one function would take care of everything on your `edit` page including validation and output to the template.  This basic CI structure is all very carefully explained in the documentation.

Comment: See:  http://ellislab.com/codeigniter/user-guide/tutorial/index.html

Comment: Yes, i am aware the tutorial and links, but nowhere explained when you load a page in template with form validation.

Comment: You might be aware of it, but if you actually read the tutorial, you'd see the validation code on this page: http://ellislab.com/codeigniter/user-guide/tutorial/create_news_items.html

Comment: Thanks, this is what i was searching, let me try this idea, thank you to point out the tutorial

Answer (score -1):

If I understand correctly, you want to display the validation errors?

Inside your View file, put the following:

Short IF-Statement Form:

```
<?php if ( validation_errors() ) :?>
<div>
   <?php echo $validation_errors();?>
</div>
<?php endif;?>
```

Regular If-Statement Form:

```
<?php if ( validation_errors() ) {?>
<div>
   <?php echo $validation_errors();?>
</div>
<?php }?>
```

[Validation Errors Doc](http://ellislab.com/codeigniter/user-guide/tutorial/create_news_items.html)